# How can I make the Twitter Tools plugin hyperlink every link?

Tags: plugins, twitter

It appears that (Twitter) shortened links are not auto-hyperlinked whilst non-shortened links are.

Is there a patch to make all links hyperlinked - therefore clickable?

E.g. http://cl.ly/image/3B2S3z472n0U

http://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter-tools/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never used this plugin. WordPress has a function called [`make_clickable()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/make_clickable) which might help you.

Example:

```
$string = "This is a long text that contains some links like http://www.wordpress.org and http://www.wordpress.com .";
echo make_clickable($string);
```

Output:

```
This is a long text that contains some links like <a href="http://www.wordpress.org" rel="nofollow">http://www.wordpress.org</a> and <a href="http://www.wordpress.com" rel="nofollow">http://www.wordpress.com</a> .
```

Comment: Brilliant.I altered twitter-tools/views/tweet.php line 8 from 'echo wptexturize($content);' to 'echo wptexturize(make_clickable($content));'

Comment: Be aware that you'll lose modifications if you update the plugin.

Comment: I know, but until an official update is released not much I an do!

Comment: You can propose the plugin author to add this option :)